# Plotting 3D graph for multi-variable regression

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, regression

I want to plot a 3D graph with the plane using the following data:

[image]

Here's the code for dataframe:

```
df_dict = {'area':[2600, 3000, 3200, 3600, 4000, 4100], 
'bedrooms':[3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0],
'age':[20, 15, 18, 30, 8, 8], 
'price':[550000, 565000, 610000, 595000, 760000, 810000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

These values are stored in a DataFrame from pandas.

Also, the equation is:

[image]

The area is x1, bedrooms are x2, and age is x3.

- `m1` is 112, `m2` is 23388, and `m3` is -3231
- `b` is 221323

I have only been able to do the following:

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(df['area'], df['bedrooms'], df['age'], c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('area')
ax.set_ylabel('bedrooms')
ax.set_zlabel('age')

plt.show()
```

Even this doesn't look right. How can I correctly draw a plane using the equation?

Comment: Can you post some sample data as a dataframe instead of an image?  Also, how do you want the plane to behave?  Should it be a flat plane that tries to get close to these points?  Or should it be a curved plane that intersects with all points?

Comment: The data is loaded from a .csv file but I will provide some code to create the dataframe.

Comment: The plane should behave normally according to the given equation.

Comment: Please, provide the csv file in order to give a large enough dataset to work with. I will show you two approaches.

Comment: @sentence: This is all the data I have actually, you can feel free to generate random values to extend it.

Comment: Or, you can tell me how large the data would you require? I can generate it and post it with values.

Answer (score 1):

The regression equation that you wish to plot would actually has 3 predictors and 1 target variable. Plotting `price` would require another axis, i.e. plotting in 4d. This simplified version of plotting a plane in 3d might be a good place to start

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def f(area, bedrooms):
    return(112*area + 23388*bedrooms + 221323)

n = 6
area = np.linspace(2600, 4100, n)
bedrooms = np.linspace(3, 6, n)

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(area, bedrooms)
Z = f(X1, X2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_xlabel('area')
ax.set_ylabel('bedrooms')
ax.set_zlabel('price')
ax.set_title('surface')
```

[image: this]

Comment: In fact, you do intentionally discard the age feature, which seems to be equally important for the OP. You should specify your design choice, which is a polite, but definitely incomplete, attempt to satisfy the author's request.

Comment: Discarding the one of the features was necessary to draw a 3d plane; I arbitrarily chose age. My design choice was of course restricted due to the original request not really being feasible.

Comment: I am not sure why it would require a 4D. The column "price" was labeled data used for the multi-variable regression model. The plane must pass through the given points (area, bedroom and age).

Comment: @user963241 Well, if we consider a 1d line `y=mx+c` to need 2 axes to plot (x and y), and a 2d plane `y=mx1+mx2+c` to need 3 axes (x, y and z), then adding one more variable will require one more axis, if you follow me.

Comment: Okay, I see. Then, is it impossible to visualize such a plot? If yes, then I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @user963241 Not necessarily impossible, but also probably not what you have in mind. What I would recommend is probably making 3 of the plots that I describe above: comparing `area, bedrooms, price`, `area, age, price` then `bedrooms, age, price`. This will give an idea of how each the predictor variable looks vs. the target variable.